# How do I use array to filter out values in autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that I want to use to filter values out, but I don't know the syntax to NOT show these rows. In other words show everything except "*BROKERED", "*Bond", "*Subordinate".

Can one of you experts help me?
'''

```
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AI$150000").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=Array("*BROKERED", 
 "*Bond", "*Subordinate"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

'''

Comment: In regards to one-liners, `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AI$150000").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="<>*BROKERED", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*Bond"` is all you can do. There is no syntax and the `<>` will not work in the array and `AutoFilter` can only accept two criteria with wildcards. A workaround would be to have a column with unique values (e.g. with an integer sequence 1,2,3...), then write the criteria column's values to an array, loop the array to find values meeting the criteria, and write the corresponding values from the unique column to an array and use it to filter the data...

Comment: in the unique column. Usually, you don't want to just look at the data, you want to do something with it e.g. delete or copy it. Why don't you share more code and what you want to do with the filtered data (if it's not obvious from the code), in other words, share more detail to receive more relevant information?